# Filtrar por fecha SQL

Tags: php, sql

Necesito generar una consulta con un filtrado por fecha (Inicio, Fin) para luego mostrarlo en pdf he hecho en php este codigo pero tiene un error a la hora de filtrar me muestra todo los meses y el filtro lo ignora:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM tabla 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta' ORDER BY id asc";
$resultado = $connect->query($query);
while($dat= $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
      $pdf->Cell(15,4,utf8_decode($dat['fecha']),1,0,'L',1);
      $pdf->Cell(0,4,utf8_decode($dat['monto']),1,1,'R',1);       
}
```

El campo **fecha** en la Tabla de la BD su formato es el siguiente (d/m/a) *01/02/2021*
Yo las variables las paso por un formulario via POST y formateo los datos

```
$desde = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['desde']));
$hasta = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['hasta']));
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, el filtro al yo ponerle en el form I: 01/05/2021 - F: 30/05/2021 me genera desde el mes 01/01/2021 hasta ...

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato es el campo fecha en la base de datos?

Comment: el tipo de dato es Text

Comment: Vale... Lo que se esta comparando es el primer digito

Comment: El problema se solucionaría cambiando el tipo de dato a (date) en el campo fecha?

Comment: Entiendo, ya este error no lo vuelvo a cometer, muchas gracias

Comment: Al final, escribí una respuesta, para que la información no se pierda en comentarios, Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo. Voy a borrar mis comentarios a la pregunta, que ya con la respuesta, carecen de sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero te explico el origen del problema:

El problema que tienes es que tienes campos tipo texto, `char`, `varchar`, o similares y esperas un comportamiento *correcto* con las fechas, pero el motor ignora por completo que lo que hay allí son fechas y no hace otra cosa que procesarlo como texto.

Tomando en cuenta que el operador `between` no es más que azúcar sintáctica, lo que estás haciendo es algo como:

```
select *
  from tabla
 where fecha >= '01/05/2021' 
   and fecha <= '30/05/2021'
```

El motor va a aplicar las reglas de comparaciones de cadenas de texto cuando aplicas operadores en la cláusula where.

Es decir, el motor va comparando caracter por caracter, y se detiene cuando puede dar un resultado para el operador aplicado; por ejemplo una comparación de igualdad, requiere que todos los caracteres sean iguales, así que tiene que compararlos todos para dar verdadero. Si encuentra uno que no sea igual antes de llegar al final, la comparación se detiene y devuelve falso.

Una comparación `>`, va a comparar el primer caracter, si ese es mayor, se detiene y devuelve verdadero. Si es menor, se detiene y devuelve falso, si es igual, pasa al segundo caracter y repite. Si llega al final de ambas cadenas con todos iguales, devuelve falso. Si llega al final de una cadena con todos iguales, devuelve verdadero si la cadena más larga está a la izquierda del operador y falso si está a la derecha.

Siguiendo esta lógica, si tienes la cadenas en formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, el between jamás te va a funcionar, como tampoco operadores de comparación que no sean de igualdad, por ejemplo >, >=, <, <=, todos van a fallar, ya que por ejemplo el texto `'25/01/1945'` es mayor que el texto `'1/12/2021'`, ya que `'2' > '1'`.

---

Alternativas de solución:

- Sin cambiar de tipo de dato: Si no quieres o no puedes cambiar de tipo de dato, lo que puedes hacer es almacenar los datos en un formato que te pueda dar el resultado esperado en comparaciones de texto, que es poner los datos más significativos al inicio y los menos significativos al final, respetando siempre la misma longitud para todas las fechas y sus segmentos.

  Por ejemplo `yyyymmdd`, o `yyyy-mm-dd`, te van a permitir hacer un between como el que buscas, y funcionarían, además de la igualdad, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, etc.
- Cambiando de tipo de dato, en mi opinión, es lo ideal. Investiga en tu motor, suele haber tipos especializados para las fechas, tales como `date`, `datetime` o similares. Este tipo de dato no solo te va a ofrecer correcta funcionalidad con todos los operadores de comparación, sino te brinda también la posibilidad de realizar aritmética de fechas, que son las operaciones que te permiten ir de una fecha a otra.

  Debes tomar en cuenta que, dependiendo del avance que tengas en el desarrollo de tu aplicación, esto puede tener un impacto y obligarte a re-hacer o ajustar partes que ya funcionaban con los campos de tipo texto y vas a tener que cambiar para manejar fechas. Básicamente inserciones, actualizaciones, etc. puede que requieran de algún ajuste. –